# Query Using != On LEFT JOIN Table Returns No Result

Tags: sql-server, database, join

I am querying a Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

The primary table (T1) structure contains account details:

AccountID, Name, Address

This table is dropped and recreated using external data nightly. We need to display this information but also need to exclude some of the records. Since we have no access to the external data we can't just add a column.

So we created a table (T2) to mark all the accounts we would like to exclude. It just has 2 fields:

AccountNo, Type

So we populated T2 and for every account we wanted to exclude from the display we gave the Type field a value of 'ex' (for exclude). We have no entries for the account we want to display.

When I execute the following query:

```
    select T1.AccountID as acct, T1.Name as name, T1.Address as add
    from T1        
    left join T2 on T1.AccountID = T2.AccountNo
    WHERE T2.Type != 'ex'
```

The above query returns and empty set.

If I run a query to look for the value 'ex' (remove the !):

```
    select T1.AccountID as acct, T1.Name as name, T1.Address as add
    from T1        
    left join T2 on T1.AccountID = T2.AccountNo
    WHERE T2.Type = 'ex'
```

The query returns the rows with that field populated with 'ex', as you expect.

I can search for NULL or NOT null with success but we need to use this extra table to do some other data manipulation in the future. In other words, we will not just be populating this field with "ex".

I'm wondering why I can't query the field in the joined table by looking for a Boolean false for a string. Is is because since the column doesn't exist in the table that is joined (T2) that it doesn't actually exist in the data set?

If that's the case how would I execute a query to return the records that do not equal a value in the joined table, whether that record exists in the joined table or not.

Comment: How about `ISNULL(T2.Type,'') != 'ex'` ?

Comment: When you explicitly search for a value on a `LEFT JOIN` table, that will force the table to be `INNER JOIN`. Use @bjones suggestion above.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ISNULL solution like mentioned in the comments.

Another way you could write the query is this:

```
SELECT #t1.AccountID AS acct, #t1.Name AS [name], #t1.Address AS [add]
FROM #t1        
LEFT JOIN #t2 ON #t1.AccountID = #t2.AccountNo
             AND #t2.type = 'ex' --In case you add additional types to #t2
WHERE #t2.AccountNo IS NULL;
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks very much!